# Rails/Grape how to store old and new data in json logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape

I'm currently trying to implement a logs for the administration section of my rails/grape application. All writing, changing and deleting accesses to the database should be logged in the future eg. password changes, export of data, deletion of any data etc.

To do so I created a separate model:

```
def change
  create_table :logged_activity do |t|
  t.string :admin_email, index: true, null: false
  t.string :admin_role, null: false
  t.string :type, null: false

  t.json :old_data
  t.json :new_data
  t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Let say admin changed their `name` from John to Joe, how to save this old value (name: John) to the json file? The `new_data` will be quite simple, just add method below in to the right place (e.g. after call for update `admin_user`) but how to save the old ones in the same time?

```
def log_activity(admin_user)
  LoggedActivity.create!(
    admin_email: admin_user.email,
    admin_role: admin_user.role,
    type: 'Update personal data',
    new_data: {
      admin_name: admin_user.name,
      created_at: Time.now,
    },
    old_data: { ?? },
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can create two more key in admin_user object. Before creating admin_user object you can store old value(s) in side json object of admin_user object.

For e.g. 
admin_user[:old_name] = old_admin_name

So your method would be

```
def log_activity(admin_user)
    //your code
    old_data: { admin_name: admin_user.old_name},
    //your code
end
```